# Подливать мАсла в огонь — почему родительный падеж?

Tags: выбор-слов, фразеология, падежи

А наливать сока в стакан? Разве так говорят?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фразеологизм: ***добавить (подлить, подливать) масла в огонь*** означает обострить и без того ненадёжную ситуацию .

С латинского: Oleum addere camino [олеум аддэрэ камино].

Здесь родительный падеж **с количественным значением**, сравнить: выпить (всю) воду — выпить (немного) воды.

Добавить, подлить масла — это добавить еще какое-то **количество** масла.

Огонь (конфликт в переносном смысле) уже горит, а вы в него еще **добавляете** горючего  (усиливаете конфликт).

Comment: Значит, долить сока в стакан (_сока_, потому что в стакане уже есть сок), но налить сок в стакан, так как мы его нальем весь или полностью заполним им стакан?

Comment: Не совсем, от ситуации зависит. Налей сок в стакан, а не в чашку (нет количественного значения). Налей мне сока в стакан (немного, не полный стакан). Вылей (оставшийся) сок в стакан, а пакет выброси.  Говорящий определяет по ситуации наличие количественного значения, характерного для Р.п. Это может быть, к примеру,  неполный стакан сока или не весь сок из бутылки.